# Create template with barcode and using data from other site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, sharepoint-online, office-365

I have problem with creating template document in SharePoint Online (Office 365). I want to create doc with barcode and data from other site collection.

I’ll try to put the field Bar Code in template (I understand that the bar code are created when the document is created) but I want to indicate where the bar code should be created (where in document).

Second problem is used data from other collection site. I can use data from other collection using InfoPath – but only for Lists. I have a list Clients on …/sites/crm/  and I want to use this clients in …/sites/documents/ on library MyCompnayDocs (when doc is created I want to choose client). Is any possibility to do like that using InfoPath? (can I use InfoPath to edit library form?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bar code only appears after it has been generated by SharePoint, so only after you save the document, reopen it and manually add the barcode to a chosen location in the document.

Even if you add "Barcode Value" Document Property to Word template it will "hard code" the barcode value to the template and not update it when you create a new document based on the template. At least that's how it worked as I just tested it with O365 and Word 2010.

It looks like Barcode image addition is just a client side functionality that takes the "Barcode Value" property of the document and creates an barcode image. Maybe if you would create some client side add-in that would use custom placeholder and use the "Barcode Value" document property as soon as it finds it to render a barcode image?

---

With InfoPath you may be able to use SharePoint Online Web Services to access items from other site collections. However, note that this [may not work in practice](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/153/t/11697.aspx) and I haven't tried it. BCS is now available in O265 but it's now know if it will solve the issue.